# Passing a string from an event to MainActivity in Android Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, parameter-passing, main-activity

The project is done in Visual Studio with Xamarin and targeted for Android.

In my simple project I have 1 activity (MainActivity). Here I create an instance of a Scanner object that will sit in background and listen for iBeacons. Once the scanner has been created I call a Start method on the scanner object.

In the constructor of the Scanner object, there will be setup an instance of a Listener object. This instance is called when ever a beacon is detected.

Cut short – my main activity makes an instance of a scanner object. On creation of the scanner object a listener object is created. This listener object will be activated when a beacon is detected.

In my MainActivity I have a multiline TextView. I want it to show the beacons found in the listener object.

What is the best way to pass this beacon ID (string) to the TextView in the main activity?

I’m new to programming in Android, so all the different concepts with blocks, intents and what have you, are a bit confusing. I would have thought it was straight forward passing data from a listener event to the TextView but this has proven more difficult then expected.

I don’t mind going slow – so please feel free to elaborate and consider me the novice I am :-D

UPDATE:
I have edited the code to make it as short as possible, and pasted it below. Hope this gives an idea.

```
[Activity(Label = "DeviceScanSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    KontaktScanner scanner;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Initialize Scanner
        scanner = new KontaktScanner(this);

        // Button actions
        startScanButton.Click += delegate
        {
            if (CheckPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation))
            {
                // Start devices scan
                scanner.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                // Ask for permissions if needed
                ...
            }
        };
    }
}

public class KontaktScanner : Java.Lang.Object, IOnServiceReadyListener
{

    IProximityManager proximityManager;

    public KontaktScanner(Context context)
    {
        // Set Space listener
        proximityManager.SetSpaceListener(new KontaktSimpleSpaceListener());
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        proximityManager.Connect(this);
    }
}


class KontaktSimpleSpaceListener : SimpleSpaceListener
{

    public void OnRegionEntered(IBeaconRegion beaconRegion)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Entered {0} region", beaconRegion.Identifier));
    }

    public void OnRegionAbandoned(IBeaconRegion beaconRegion)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Abandoned {0} region", beaconRegion.Identifier));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code where you are trying to create the object and where you are trying to pass the string.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi - I've added parts of the code now. I need to be able to pass the log.info text back to the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Pass the context here:

```
public KontaktScanner(Activity activity)
{
    // Set Space listener
    proximityManager.SetSpaceListener(new KontaktSimpleSpaceListener(activity));
}
```

Then:

```
class KontaktSimpleSpaceListener : SimpleSpaceListener
{
    Activity context
    public KontaktSimpleSpaceListener(Activity activity)
    {
        this.context = activity; 
    }

    public void OnRegionEntered(IBeaconRegion beaconRegion)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Entered {0} region", beaconRegion.Identifier));
        MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity) context;
        myActivity.updateTextView("My Data");// pass the string here.
    }

    public void OnRegionAbandoned(IBeaconRegion beaconRegion)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Abandoned {0} region", beaconRegion.Identifier));
        MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity) context;
        myActivity.updateTextView("My another data");// pass the string here.
    }
}
```

Then create method in `MainActivity`:

```
public void updateTextView(string s) 
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        yourTextView.Text = s;//set your TextView here
    });
}
```

I have not checked the syntax but something like this should work.

Comment: My problem is that the classes and methods are definded by the supplier of the iBeacons. I'm using their SDK so I can't change the constructor of the class KontaktSimpleSpaceListner to include the Activity.
The same goes for KontaktScanner where you have changed the parameters from Context to Activity.
And I thik that's the key of my problem! How do I reference the main UI from a callback / event in a class that is not designed by me ?

Comment: @public-profile try creating your own classes extending KontaktSimpleSpaceListener and KontaktScanner and create constuctor there and you can override/implement methods.

Comment: Ok - I'll see if that approach can work. But I still don't understand why it is so difficault to reference the object responsible for handling the UI. I mean - is there an App without a UI ?? Anyway - this is not your problem :-) But to me it's starange, and I guess it's because I havn't been able to figure out the smartness in the Android architecture.